# HTML Image tags in Tab Content not rendering

Tags: html, css, image, tabs

I'm trying to design a HTML div of class type nav-tabs with tab-contents as images but the images are not rendering within the `<div class="tab-content"></div>`

But works outside the `<div class="tab-content"></div>`. I'm not able to figure why this is happening.

Preview of UI
[image: Shirt Chart]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1482566171.png))</sub>

File Structure

[image: File Structure]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1482566517.png))</sub>

This is the HTML Syntax

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="chart">
                <div class="col-md-12 selectboxit-container tshirt-chart-div">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#quote">Size Chart</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Product Type <span class="caret"></span> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                                <li onclick="renderChart('roundNeck')"><a id="roundNeck" href="#quote">Round Neck T-Shirt</a></li>
                                <li onclick="renderChart('collarNeck')"><a id="collarNeck" href="#quote">Collar Shirt</a></li>
                                <li onclick="renderChart('hoodie')"><a id="hoodie" href="#quote">Hoddie</a></li>
                                <li onclick="renderChart('roundNeck')"><a id="hoodieZipper" href="#quote">Hoddie Zipper</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="gender" class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="gender" value="0">Male</button>
                        <button type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="gender" value="1">Female</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 bs-example">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#small">S</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#medium">M</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#large">L</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#xlarge">XL</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#xxlarge">XXL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="small" class="tab-pane fade in active"><img id="cs" src="./img/chart/round-boy-s.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="medium" class="tab-pane fade"><img id="cm" src="./img/chart/round-boy-m.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="large" class="tab-pane fade "><img id="cl" src="./img/chart/round-boy-l.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="xlarge" class="tab-pane fade"><img id="cxl" src="./img/chart/round-boy-xl.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="xxlarge" class="tab-pane fade"><img id="cxxl" src="./img/chart/round-boy-xxl.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you check on your pc or hosting server?

Comment: Its in PC (localhost)

Comment: I think you have a problem with img path. It starts with `./img/` in all of my peges i haven't `.` (dots)

Comment: The path img paths are right it is issue with the `class="tab-pane"` if I remove it img is displayed but I need `class="tab-pane"`. Still cant figure out how to overcome this blocker

Comment: Show your CSS code then :)

Comment: Fixed the issue fault with CSS. Thanks Adrian

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with CSS I had defined 
`.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: none;
}`

After removing it the images are rendering

[image: Result]